# Heroku Nodejs Error sock=backend at=error code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted"

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, heroku

I have a nodejs server, working locally and also was working in heroku before last deployment .
Now When I do a new request I get always this Error

```
**sock=backend at=error code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted" method=POST path="/auth/token" host=kayyonode2.herokuapp.com request_id=1428f74a-d3d1-48b2-a830-41b0d3883f2d fwd="105.108.229.6" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=369ms status=503 bytes=1003 protocol=https**
```

I dunno what to do to fix it

Comment: this [this heroku help page](https://help.heroku.com/18NDWDW0/debugging-h18-server-request-interrupted-errors-in-nodejs-applications) help?